# Netlify form - after submit it redirects to wrong page

Tags: forms, gatsby, netlify, netlify-function

I've got a Gatsby.js project that is ran from Netlify. For a contact form I'm using Netlify's api.

The content is multilingual so I've got a contact page on `/contact/` and `/en/contact/` These obviously share the same code for a form. I've created a successful form submit page on `/form-succes/` and `/en/form-succes/`

But when I'm on the Dutch side and I submit the form I see the url go to `/form-succes` for a split second, and then it goes (redirects?) to `/en/form-succes`

It runs well on a local env but not after build on Netlify.

Is this a Netlify issue or did I do something wrong?

This is part of the form:

var `pathPrefix` is, depending on the language `/` or `/en/`

```
<form
  name={"contact"}
  method="post"
  netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
  data-netlify="true"
  lassName="contact-forms"
  action={`${pathPrefix}form-succes`} // "/form-succes" or "/en/form-succes"
          >
   // input stuff
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up makeing two Netlify Forms. One for each language. The documentation as Netlify provides is does not work.

`name={'${pathPrefix}-contact'}` (use backticks)